# Apply CSS to outside class only

Tags: css

Here's something I've been trying to work out - and failed.

Some simple html

```
<div class="md-material">
    <div class="md-material">don't apply styles to this one</div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is apply styling to the outside class only - so if it happens to be a child leave it.

I've used various combinations of `:not` without success.

Here's what I'm currently using - which works - but doesn't seem like the right answer.

```
.md-material   {
    margin-left: -8px;
    width: calc(~"100% + 16px");
}
.md-material .md-material   {
    margin-left: 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Will `:not` work, or it this outside the scope?

Comment: Can't you just override the styling with .md-material > .md-material?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT EDIT:** If you are OK with a non-CSS solution, you can use jQuery to apply it. Check out this snippet:

```js
$(".md-material:not(.md-material .md-material)").addClass("parent-style");
```

```css
.md-material {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.parent-style {
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: calc(~"100% + 16px");
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="md-material">
  Styled
  <div class="md-material">Not Styled</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** *Seems like it only works on Safari.*
Apparently, Safari has implemented complex selectors in `:not`, which is actually css4. For more compatible solutions, kindly check on other answers. Will update if I discovered a work around.

Original Answer:

Hope this is what you want. Not the style you are specifying though, but you should get the idea.

```css
.md-material:not(.md-material .md-material)   {
    margin-left: -8px;
    width: calc(~"100% + 16px");
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.md-material   {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="md-material">
    Styled
    <div class="md-material">Not Styled</div>
</div>
```

Comment: whats the difference in the styled and not styled ?

Comment: The difference is the font size.

Comment: This does indeed work - for some reason I didn't think :not could be used this way.

Comment: If you feel my answer helped you, please accept it :)

Comment: @RichardYan - sorry but on further inspection it doesn't work - it does stop the styling propagating down to the child but it doesn't apply it to the parent either. Run yur code snippet and you'll find the font size is the same.

Comment: @JohnOhara wow, actually it looked good on Safari, but when I checked on Chrome it does look the same. I'll check on that.

Comment: I'm viewing Chrome too.

Comment: not working on chrome .. that's why i thought there's no difference .. sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom `data-attribute` for it.
Below is example

```css
.md-material[data-main="main"]   {
    margin-left: -8px;
    width: calc(~"100% + 16px");
    background:tomato;
    color:blue;
}
.md-material .md-material   {
    margin-left: 0;
    width:100%;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="md-material" data-main="main">
    HELLO 
    <div class="md-material">don't apply styles to this one</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Lokesh - I've no doubt it works but I don't see it as a step forward. In my existing CSS, I add a few lines of code to negate the styling - but only need to do it once. With your solution, I have to add another data tag or even class to every occurance, which is more maintenance.